# Theme folder - cannot access permissions

Tags: gnome, permissions, themes

I am very new to Ubuntu and couldn't find a straight forward answer or solution to this:

1. I'm running Ubuntu GNOME 13.10 and I have installed Tweak Tool. Running fine.
2. I've downloaded the MediterraneanNight Series 2.03 theme and extracted it to the desktop.
3. I have enabled viewing of hidden files and located /usr/share/themes, I can see the existing theme files located inside: Adwaita, HighContrast etc
4. The problem - I cannot drag and drop the newly extracted theme into the theme folder. I have located the permissions tab via theme folder properties, this indicates Owner and Group as root, Others has no value. All three drop-downs are transparent/faded and inaccessible. 'You are not the owner, so you cannot change these permissions'.

How can I solve this please?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to run it as root.

```
sudo -H nautilus  # Replace `nautilus` with your file manager
```

Then, navigate to your desktop (in `/home/username/Desktop`), and drag & drop into `/usr/share/themes`.

Comment: You beauty. That worked perfectly. Cheers!